# Show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism using modular arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

The following proof should show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, by making use of a modular arithmetic property:

\begin{equation}
(A+B) \mod {C} = (A \text{ mod C} + B \text{ mod C}) \mod {C}
\end{equation}

I would like to get some feedback if the below proof makes sense and if I used the modular arithmetic property in a correct way.

---

**Proposition:**

For any integer $n \ge 2$, the mapping $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

\begin{align*}
\phi: (\mathbb{Z}, +) &\longrightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_n, +_n) \\
                    k &\longrightarrow k_{\text{mod}\ n}
\end{align*}

(Note that the notation $k_{\text{mod}\ n}$ is the remainder of $k$ divided by $n$.)

**Proof:**

- Let $n$ be an integer with $n \ge 2$, and let $\phi$ be the mapping defined above. Let $r, s \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now:

\begin{align}
\phi(r) +_n \phi(s) &= r_{\text{mod}\ n} +_n s_{\text{mod}\ n} \nonumber \\
                    &= (r \text{ mod n} +  s \text{ mod n}) &\mod {n} \tag{1} \\
                    &= (r + s)                   &\mod {n} \tag{2}
\end{align}

$(1)$ is by definition of $+_n$ and $k_{\text{mod}\ n}$, then $(2)$ holds because of the addition property of modular arithmetic.

- Also, we find $\phi(r + s) = (r + s) \mod n$.
- Thus $\phi(r) +_n \phi(s) = \phi(r + s)$ is true, which shows that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Comment: It looks fine. But perhaps you can elaborate more on the step you go from (1) to (2), because it is simply a rewriting of the function $\phi$. I would rather use the definition of $\phi$ which is performing integer division and taking the remainder. So my suggestion is that you write $r=pn + r'$ for $0\leq r' < n$ and similarly with $s$, by definition $r'$ is a representative of ($r\pmod{n}$).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, both! @mathma If I understood correctly you would suggest to rewrite the line labelled $(1)$ like so $...= (pn + r') + (mn + s') \mod n) = ...$ and define $0 \le r' < n$ and $0 \le s' < n$, is that what you mean? : )

Comment: @Max I just saw that you assumed the property that congruence classes modulo $n$ are additive. Then it is not necessary that you clarify that step because it is assumed to be true